# javascript score function school assignment

Tags: javascript, html

I've been struggling with my javascript function for my school assignment. I'm trying make a point system and testing it on my Index page first. Whats supposed to happen is when I press the button on the left it should restart the game and ask for a username which works but the button on the right is supposed to award 12 points it works for the first click but when clicked again it stays on twelve. I've asked this question before someone helped a bit but before I saw it the question was removed so I could not ask how to fix it completely.

My html index page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Index </title>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<center><font size="200" color="white">Treasure hunt</font>
<br>
<br>
<p style="padding: 10px; border: 2px solid black;">
<font size="5" color="white">
Hello and Welcome to the Treasure Hunt!
<br>
You are a treasure hunter, beware there are false links, which are obvious, and there are true links which are hidden. 
<br>
The wrong link will lead you nowhere, the right link will lead you to the treasure.
<br>
 Also You have limited lives, so don't keep clicking on those obvious links.

False links that take you in a circle (wrong turns)
<br>
Hidden links which take you to the next stage
<br>
Whenever you take a wrong turn(<a href="page1.html"><font color="white">bad link </a>  )you will be penalized (losing lives)
</font>
</p>


<br>
<a href="page2.html"><font size="50">click here quick to go to the next page!</font>  </a>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="reset(); askName();"></button>
<button onclick="winPoints()"></button>
<body background="thc.JPG">
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript function page:

```
function askName () {
 
    var name = window.prompt ("Arrr what be your name? ");


    sessionStorage.setItem("username" , name);

}


function reset() {
    sessionStorage.setItem ("score" , 0);
    sessionStorage.setItem ("lives" , 3);
    sessionStorage.setItem ("username" , "");
}

function winPoints(points) {
    var pointsToWin = parseInt("12");

    var currentScore = +sessionStorage.getItem("score");

    if (currentScore == 0) {
        sessionStorage.setItem ("score" , pointsToWin + currentScore);
        alert("You have " + pointsToWin + " points");
    } else {
        sessionStorage.setItem ("Score" , currentScore + pointsToWin);
        alert("You have " + currentScore + " points");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem*". Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add a `+` in front of `+sessionStorage.getItem("score")`, otherwise it is treated as a string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this for your winPoints javascript function.

```js
function winPoints() {
    let currentScore = Number(sessionStorage.getItem("score"));
    sessionStorage.setItem("score" , currentScore+=12);
    alert("You have " + currentScore + " points");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to fix it thanks to this.